# fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc9.h: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc

I am trying to compile a Linux kernel. I followed instructions and installed tools. But I am stuck at this. GCC is installed and the version is 9 but still, it says cannot find the header. I am building on ubuntu. If I try to use the old GCC, the new GCC 9 automatically gets installed along with old one. if I uninstall the new one then the command disappears, setting up an alias does not help.

I am really fed up with the incompatibility of this building process with windows due to header files. How it comes that I have installed compiler and it does not have support with old commands. Like what kind of upgrade is this to GCC, you are unable to build an old source with the new version of the tool.?

I am actually trying to build genymotion kernel source code from github.

anyway, I want to find a solution to this, If you know please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us your version of Ubuntu and kernel version and what version of kernel you are attempting to build. As far as I know, there is no file called `compiler-gcc9.h`, which is consistent with the error message you get. However, there is a file called `compiler-gcc.h`, which is also what I would expect, i.e. a non versioned one.

Comment: 54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 , and trying to build   Linux kernel release 3.x, Genymotion kernel from github source

Answer (score 1):

Use apt-file search to determine what package supplies the file:

```
$ apt-file search compiler-gcc9.h
backport-iwlwifi-dkms: /usr/src/backport-iwlwifi-8324/backport-include/linux/compiler-gcc9.h
```

So install the backport-iwlwifi-dkms package:

```
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```